# What does mov edx, [x+4] do in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, memory-address

In assembly language, what does the second line of code do? What happened when this code was executed?

```
x DWORD 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

mov edx, [x+4]
```

Comment: @ErikEidt: `dword` is 32-bit, so this loads the value `2`.  You're mixing this up with their previous question, [In assembly language what does MOV ax, \[x + (TYPE x)\*2 -4\] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74039867) , where `x` had type `WORD`.

Comment: @PeterCordes: oops!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mov` is an instruction which copies data between registers, or to/from a specified memory location.

TLDR:  `mov edx, [x+4]` loads a `dword` (4 bytes) starting from the fourth byte of `x` (which has value = 2), into the `edx` register.

---

In the memory the `x` array can be seen as:

```
0x00000001,
0x00000002,
0x00000003,
0x00000004,
0x00000005,
0x00000006,
0x00000007,
0x00000008
```

The address of `x` corresponds to the first byte of `0x00000001`. The fourth byte after `x` is the first byte of `0x00000002`. After this byte 32 bits are loaded into `edx`. So in the end the value `0x00000002` is inside `edx`.